# Personal AI-based learning platform or app

Tags: artificial-intelligence, learning

I found [Zavvy](https://zavvy.io), a AI-based learning management system. It looks like it's meant for teams/businesses. I just want an app with which I can easily learn what I need as if I were talking with a teacher. It can be paid, but affordable for individuals like me.

<s>Or, I mean, it looks like it's not just for teams, but it has a lot of packages and I'm confused now</s>